# Show location bar in Firefox

Tags: javascript, popup

How can I show the location bar on a FireFox popup when the location bar is hidden on the main window? The code below creates a popup but no location bar.

**JS:**

```
function newPopup(url) {
   popupWindow = window.open(
       url,'popUpWindow','height=300,width=400,location=yes');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="" onclick="return newPopup('http://www.mx7racing.com)">;pop with location bar</a>;
```

Comment: You cannot change the location bar settings - its a browser preference and allowing the hiding / display of it using code would open up security issues

Answer (score 0):

Maybe target="_blank" attribute helps you.

```
<a href="http://www.mx7racing.com" target="_blank">;pop with location bar</a>;
```